# Can I make the missions easier?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

**I'm having trouble with a mission**, and I'm retrying over and over again without any success.

Is there any way to make the mission easier or some sort of assistance that I can call in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Getting the odds in your favor

Sometimes the game can seem daunting and difficult, sometimes it just feels like you've hit a brick wall.

**Here are some features to help you clear your missions.**

### Buddy

Having a buddy in the game is awesome. But, sometimes, you need to make sure that you're using the correct one.

**For example:** there's no reason to be using Quiet if she can't access the area where you're carrying out the mission.

[image: Quiet]

### Chicken Hat

If you've struggled with the mission for a long time and had to retry several times then you might already know of this one.

The chicken hat is given *automatically* to anyone struggling with a mission, but you can also activate it manually in the Game Settings menu.

[image: Chicken Hat]

The feature of this very stylish looking hat? You will be *a lot* harder to spot. And I really mean *a lot*.

The hat grants a form of quasi-invisibility, rendering you almost invisible.

**Please note, however, that use of this hat will restrict the mission score to a maximum of an A grade.**

### Air Support

Air support is a big, big advantage for you.

You can knock your enemies out with sleeping gas, change weather conditions or disperse smoke.

Think of this as a get-out-of-jail-free card. If you've been on a long mission and see a heavily guarded outpost up ahead. Just use the sleep gas and make them go nighty night.

[image: Air support]

**Air support, just like the Chicken Hat restricts your mission score to that of an A grade.**

Comment: You can also call in your heli to give support with it's miniguns and rockets if you research and equip them. It can be shoot down which will cost a bit to replace though

Comment: Pretty sure that classifies as air support, though.

Comment: I'll have to check later but I'm pretty sure the chopper doesn't limit your score.

Comment: Yeah, would be awesome to find out if it's air support or not.

Comment: It isn't in air support but calling it in to help fight has the A rank restriction, I have however had a pickup heli come help be before and that doesn't have the restriction and I'm not sure if it kicks in if it helps

Comment: I think the game only makes the distinction based on what option you chose when you called in the support chopper. Calling it in for pick-up is okay and doesn't limit your rank. However, I've never seen the chopper make any aggressive moves (even when under fire upon entry) when I called it in for pick-up; the only way to defend yourself while being extracted is to use the minigun (or whatever arms you are carrying). Using the minigun while you're being extracted doesn't reduce your score or anything.

Comment: In addition you can develop an stealth gizzo that will cloak you for some time.

Comment: Another fun option is that if you die a bunch with the chicken hat on, you can unlock the lil' chicken hat. The lil' chicken hat makes you permanently invisible to guards and cameras. The downside is that it restricts your mission score to 0.